# function that is supposed to be interactive, but it works only once

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'll start with the code then I'll explain:

```
     <section>
        <div id="flex">
            <img id="bulb1" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
            <img id="bulb2" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
            <img id="bulb3" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
        </div>
    </section>




function luce(bulb) {
if (bulb == "bulb1") {
    var bulbsw = document.getElementById('bulb1');
    if(bulbsw.src == "images/lighton.png") {
        bulbsw.src = "images/lightoff.png";
    } else {
        bulbsw.src = "images/lighton.png";
    }
}
}
```

The javascript code is in an external file, then no worries I have pasted it in this way to let you read it. I have three images, they represent three bulbs off. When I click on bulb1 all good, it goes on. Now I expect that if I click on bulb1 again it goes off, but nothing happens, why? Sorry I'm a beginner and I'm doing exercises to improve. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried pressing f12 on your browser to check the dev console for errors?

Comment: The problem is that the `<img>`'s `src` is not `images/lighton.png` is actually something like `https://example.com/images/lighton.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this script - either locally or from a webserver - the string which gets returned by querying the **.src** property of an image element doesn't consist of the path and the image only.

For example if you run it locally inside a folder called bulb on your d: drive it will return

```
file:///d:/bulb/images/lightoff.png
```

That means as soon as the luce function gets called it will jump right into the else block because `if(bulbsw.src == "images/lighton.png")` evaluates to false.
The next time you click on that same bulb it will jump straight into the else block again because there is no way this will ever evaluate to true.

You can workaround by extracting just the filename + the extension and use this for the comparison.

```js
function luce(bulb) {
  if (bulb == "bulb1") {
    var bulbsw = document.getElementById('bulb1');
    var bulbImage = bulbsw.src.substring(bulbsw.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, bulbsw.src.length);
    if (bulbImage == "lighton.png") {
      bulbsw.src = "lightoff.png";
    } else {
      bulbsw.src = "lighton.png";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="flex">
    <img id="bulb1" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
    <img id="bulb2" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
    <img id="bulb3" src="images/lightoff.png" onclick="luce(this.id)" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to try many things but then I got what you meant. Your code works, but it works also changing the path to this: file:///Users/leon/Desktop/Course/bulbs/images/lightoff.png, then since I'm in local, I just changed the path to complete my exercise, I had no idea about the path, I thought was index.html the root. Thank you again, I really appreciated your help.

Comment: No problem Leon - glad I could help! By the way, if you think this is the right answer, be sure to accept it.

Comment: sorry I didn't know I could click on that :) I did it, thank you again